# Oracle SOA composite application, BPEL human task implementation assignee not able to see the requested form data

Tags: oracle, soa, jdeveloper, business-process-management

Recently I've been working on Oracle SOA suit and working on human task implementation for the "Purchase Order" application.

The scenario is that if the purchase order value is greater than the specified limit then it should be manually approved by the Assignee. Now when I test the web service it process successfully and the BPEL process is in running state untill the assignee approves the order manually. When I check the same in worklist, the form lables are showing perfectly for the assigned task but the submitted form values(in web service test) is not showing there.
Below is the screenshot of soa composite:

[image]

Below is the screenshot of worklist view:

[image]

Thanks for viewing this problem and please help me if anyone know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured out the solution myself. Basically for the Human task, I need to set the Task Name via the edit icon provided just after the task title text box and this would appear the task title as <%Approve Order%>, earlier it was manually entered in the same text box as 'Approve Order'.

[image: Human task title assignment via editor]

Now this human task will be invoked for the specified scenario for Purchase Order Processing project.